# Regex: Remove space around single character(s)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I achieve desired result?

Target string: `"Text where s o m e parts are s h r u n k"`

Regex: `(\s+)(\S)\s+`

Repalce with: `$2`

Desired result: `Text where some parts are shrunk`

Current result: `Text wheresome parts areshrunk`

Comment: How are you going to handle instances where character `a` is used. Example: `a w o r d`

Comment: Use word boundaries: '\b'. \s+(\b\S\b)\s+

Comment: It's a legal name of an entity so I don't expect such a grammatical detail to be present in the text...

Comment: @OnlineCop: Tried that before..

Comment: I don't think this is possible, mainly because of what @B.K. said.  Same applies for 'I'.  Possible for your example, sure, but not for any/all arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 1):

Search: `\b(\S)\s+(?=\S\b)`
Replace: `$1` (no spaces before/after)

[regex101 example](http://regex101.com/r/uY8pF1/1)

This uses a look-ahead that first searches for a singular character (separated by whitespace) and then "peeks forward" to see if more singular characters occur further down the line. If that's true, replace the result with only the captured character, removing all the excess whitespace between them.

Comment: Nice! Would you mind adding some explanation around it?

Comment: `This is n o t a valid solution`

Comment: It works, it's just needs $1 replacement.. Is that why it is not valid?

Comment: I wonder if it isn't regarding the floating 'a' that should be left apart ('not a' vs 'nota').

Comment: @OnlineCop: As I've mentioned above, gramar does not apply as it's a company name.

Comment: Do no company names have such structure? Unless you're working with a known, finite list then yes, some will.